# Using xml custom file as string.xml

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm using Android SQLite in my app, I want put all my static query (cration, delete, update) into a specific file (I hate sql merged with java code).
so, I want create a file called query.xml and use that as string.xml

```
context.getString(R.query.MY_STATIC_QUERY)
```

but I think that is not possible.

there's a method to do that? (or something like that?)

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do..you can put all your query in property file and wherever needed read from the property file.